# mongodb- aggregate to get counts.

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've been learning mongodb and I'm a little stuck writing a query.

I have the following collection:

```
{
    _id : 1,
    House: A,
    inventory: [
        {
            place: Kitchen,
            item: fridge
        },
        {
            place: Kitchen,
            item: stove
        },
        {
            place: Kitchen,
            item: TV
        },
        {
            place: Bedroom,
            item: bed
        },
        {
            place: Bedroom,
            item: TV
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id : 2,
    House: B,
    inventory: [
        {
        ....
        }
    ]
},
```

How would I write a query to return the count of the "places" and "items"? So the output should be like this:
{id: Kitchen, PlaceCount: 3, itemCount: 3} - 3 kitchen,3 items(fridge,stove,TV)

{id: Bedroom, PlaceCount: 2, itemCount: 2} - 2 Bedroom, 2 items(bed,TV)

I need the TV count to be counted within each place.

Comment: Hoi and welcome! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: have you tried db.user.aggregate({ $group : {_id : "$inventory.place", PlaceCount: { $sum : 1 },itemCount: { $sum : 1 } } }, { $match : { } }, { $sort : {_id : 1} }) ?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao I did, it produces `{ "_id" : [ "Kitchen", "Kitchen", "Kitchen", "Bedroom", "Bedroom" ], "PlaceCount" : 1, "itemCount" : 1 }`, which doesn't make too much sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with the [Aggregation Pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), which allows you to aggregate your data in multiple steps that you provide passing an array.

Your aggregation should be:

```
db.your_collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$inventory" },
  {$group: { _id: "$inventory.place", placeCount:{$sum : 1}, items : {$push: "$inventory.item"}}},
  {$project: { placeCount: 1, itemsCount : {$size: "$items"}}}
])
```

Explained:

1. [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) producing one result for each of your inventory elements
2. [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) the unwinded inventory elements by place, requiring a count (using [`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)) and an array of items (still by place, using [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/))
3. [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the following data of your grouped results from previous step: the placeCount and the size (using [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)) of your items array, which is the itemsCount

Comment: Project is the only thing i'm not clear about but i'll read the documentation. thanks for the explanation